# MongoDB Java Driver Equivalent of Snapshot for MongoCursor

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

After upgrading my MongoDB Java driver from version 2.14 to 3.2, I changed from using [DBCursor](https://api.mongodb.org/java/2.14/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html) to [MongoCursor](https://api.mongodb.org/java/3.2/com/mongodb/client/MongoCursor.html).

Previously, I was using `snapshot()` to prevent repetition when iterating through my large database of thousands of documents. However, I can't seem to find equivalent method for MongoCursor. This is causing troubling repetitions, e.g. 5571 loops for 4493 documents. That's like 24% more iterations! OMG!

So, my question is, is there a simple way or an equivalent method for MongoCursor that can prevent this from happening? If not, should I switch back to using DBCursor? It looks to still be supported in version 3.2.

Please kindly advise! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After banging a few things through an checking the profiler logs I actually got a confirmation on this:

```
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().modifiers(
    new Document("$snapshot", true)
).iterator();
```

So you need to call the [`.modifiers()`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/client/FindIterable.html#modifiers-org.bson.conversions.Bson-) while still on a [`FindIterable`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/client/FindIterable.html) with `$snapshot` as `true`. This is consistent over the wire with the [`.snaphot()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.snapshot/#cursor.snapshot) cursor modifier.

Both record in the profiler like this:

```
   "query" : {
            "find" : "sample",
            "filter" : {

            },
            "snapshot" : true
    },
```

Showing the correct modifier placed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just couldn't find it, >_< @Blakes Seven. It is working perfectly! :)

Comment: @Tacocat Though I was "pretty sure" it was `$snapshot`, even I wanted to run this through the query profiler a few times to make sure that all invocations were the same, as is mentioned. The Java docs do quite sadly leave a lot to be desired in terms of clarity.

Comment: :( good to hear that I am not alone in struggling by, @Blakes Seven